# AngularJs Broadcast Unit Testing Error

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am very new to AngularJs and doing unit testing. I am having this issue with a test I wrote and it is giving me this error, I realize there might be some errors with brackets but I am just giving a sample of the code to understand how I need to test against it.

```
Expected spy $broadcast to have been called with [ 'dataSamplesReceived', Object({ newDataSamples: Object({  }) }) ]
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('fileUploadCtrl',
        function($scope, $rootScope, $log, fileUpload) {
     $scope.uploadFile = function () {
                    var file = $scope.sampleFile;
                    $rootScope.$broadcast("sampleFilesSelected", {
                        newSampleFiles: file
                    });
                        .success(function (data) {
                            $rootScope.$broadcast("dataSamplesReceived", {
                                newDataSamples: data
                            });
                        })
                        .error(function (data) {
                            alert("Upload failed");
                        });
                } // uploadFile
```

**spec.js**

```
    describe('test broadcast for new file opload ', function () {
    var $controller, $rootScope;

    beforeEach(function () {
        module('app');
        inject(function (_$rootScope_, _$controller_) {
            $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
            spyOn($rootScope, '$broadcast').and.callThrough();
            $controller = _$controller_;
        });
    });

    it("should select/upload new sample files", function () {
        $controller('fileUploadCtrl', {

            $scope: $rootScope.$new(),

            file: {}
        })
        expect($rootScope.$broadcast).toHaveBeenCalledWith('sampleFilesSelected', {newSampleFiles: {}})
    });


    it("should recieve data samples", function () {
        $controller('fileUploadCtrl', {

            $scope: $rootScope.$new(),

            data: {}
        })
        expect($rootScope.$broadcast).toHaveBeenCalledWith('dataSamplesReceived', {newDataSamples: {}})
    });
})
```

Comment: spyOn($rootScope, '$broadcast'); followed by $rootScope.$new() looks suspect

Answer (score 0):

this is working for me ...

```
spyOn(state, 'go').and.callThrough();
// blah blah 
expect(state.go).toHaveBeenCalledWith('home');
```

try ...

```
spyOn($rootScope, '$broadcast').and.callThrough();
expect($rootScope.$broadcast).toHaveBeenCalledWith('dataSamplesReceived', {newDataSamples: {}})
```

Comment: I went ahead and tried youur suggestion and updated my code up top to reflect. However it says " Expected spy $broadcast to have been called with [ 'sampleFilesSelected', Object({ newSampleFiles: Object({  }) }) ] but it was never called." And for the other test as well for 'dataSamplesReceived'